# Bootstrap 5 carousel slide not working for first image

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm building a page with Angular and Bootstrap 5 and have installed a carousel on one of the pages. According to the instructions, I have omitted the data attributes, as the default values fit perfectly for me.

The carousel is displayed and I can call up the previous and next image with the buttons on the left and right. Now I despair of the swipe function. When I load the page, swipe does not work and there are no console entries. But if I click once on one of the buttons for the previous or next picture, swiping also works afterwards.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
          <title>Placeholder 1</title>
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">First
            slide</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
          <title>Placeholder 2</title>
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second
            slide</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
          <title>Placeholder 3</title>
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Third
            slide</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried the following already:

- On the bootstrap website swiping is working at least in the examples "With controls" and "Crossfade" without using one of the buttons first
- I created a jsfiddle with a copy of one of the bootstrap samples which also did not work
- I tried swiping with Chrome desktop in mobile device mode and also with my android phone